# Electron MSI package name ends with machine why?

Tags: electron, windows-installer, electron-forge

I have created package using electron forge (maker/wix).

I am able to generate msi package by using electron forge configuration. But I am facing 1 issue.

After the installation I am getting installed package along with (Machine) e.g.: applicationname**(Machine)**.

Also I have tried with signed package but still it seems issues occur.

Any idea why this issue raises and how to resolve this?